# Laravel orderBy using 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Please don't tell me to put the orderBy inside the function, because that doesn't work. kill_count and death_count are columns of the `roleplay` relationship

here is my full code:

```
$topCredits = Player::whereHas("roleplay", function($q) {
            $q->where('government_id', '<', '1');
        })->orderBy('credits', 'DESC')->limit(10)->get();

        $topKills = Player::whereHas("roleplay", function($q) {
            $q->where('government_id', '<', '1')->orderBy('kill_count', 'DESC');
        })->limit(10)->get();

        $topDeaths = Player::whereHas("roleplay", function($q) {
            $q->where('government_id', '<', '1')->orderBy('death_count', 'DESC');
        })->limit(10)->get();
```

Now, the first `$topCredits` works perfectly, but the bottom 2 don't. They work very well except for the fact it doesn't order by the death_count and kill_count, can anyone help with this? The `roleplay` is a relationship of hasOne on both sides.

Comment: What is the relation between Player and Roleplay?

Comment: HasOne and HasOne

Answer (score 0):

The orderBy in the whereHas would not have any effect on players. Since whereHas is a subquery of Payers.

```
 $topKills = Player::whereHas("roleplay", function($q) {
      $q->where('government_id', '<', '1');
  })->leftJoin("roleplay","roleplay.player_id","=","players.id")
   ->select("players.*")
   ->orderBy('roleplay.kill_count', 'DESC')
   ->limit(10)
   ->get();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Instead of hard coding the table name, is there a way I can get it from the model?

Comment: With joins, no.

Comment: @oseintow Since it is a HasOne relation, you can use an INNER JOIN and move `->where('government_id', '<', '1')` to the outer query. `whereHas` wouldnt be needed that way.

Comment: `$roleplayTable = (new Roleplay)->getTable();` and then `leftJoin($rolePlayTable, $roleplayTable . '.player_id', '=', 'players.id')`